# How to use aggregate functions in Tortoise ORM?

Tags: postgresql, count, max, aggregate-functions, tortoise-orm

1. I need just **count entities** *(e.g., for users table)*

Of course I can:

```
count = (await Users.all()).count()
```

but it is not optimal: it get all entities at first, and after just find len() of list entities.

2. I need just **find max** id

I found such way in docs:

```
max_id = (await User.annotate(max_id=Max("id")).values_list("max_id", flat=True))[0]
```

but it is overcomplicated again, I don't want to query whole entity at first and write so much for getting just f**king `last_insert_id` number.

---

I want some simple way like `count = await User.count()` and `max_id = await Users.max('id')`

But the best way I've found so far is raw db queries bypassing the orm and I'm frustrated with that:(